# Select All Checkbox with Trigger - jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, eventtrigger

On my SelectAll checkbox and click trigger should work for all input - which has on-click event on it.

**trigger working on selectall, but uncheck selectall not working. its didnt uncheck all input**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" />

<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_1" value="1" onclick="javascript: total_select(1,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">

<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_2" value="2" onclick="javascript: total_select(2,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">

<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_3" value="3" onclick="javascript: total_select(3,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">
```

Below what i have did

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SelectAll").click(function () {
      $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
        $(".checkBoxClass").change(function(){
            if (!$(this).attr("checked")){
                $("#SelectAll").attr("checked",false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above Jquery working for select-all / UN-select all checkbox - which works if i remove below trigger

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#SelectAll").click(function(){
           $(".checkBoxClass").trigger("click"); 
           $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', true);    // if i remove this line then selectall for checkbox don't works            
     }); 
 });
```

but i need above jquery to trigger - total_select function

```
function total_select(id,carat,price){

  var lenChkBox = $("input[name='pid[]']:checked").length;

      if(document.getElementById("pid_"+id).checked==true) {

         total_select.s++;                                  
         document.getElementById("noofs").innerHTML=total_select.s;

          total_select.c +=carat;
          var cs = (total_select.c).toFixed(2);
          document.getElementById("carat").innerHTML=cs;

          total_select.p +=price * carat;
          avg_price_per = total_select.p/total_select.c;
          var ca = (avg_price_per).toFixed(2);

          document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="$"+ca;

    } else {
            total_select.s--;
           document.getElementById("noofs").innerHTML=total_select.s;

            total_select.c -=carat;
            cs = (total_select.c).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("carat").innerHTML=cs;

            total_select.p -=price * carat;
            avg_price_per = total_select.p/total_select.c;
            var ca = (avg_price_per).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="$"+ca;
}
```

i tried many :

```
   $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
   $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
```

but still not working , it do check all input on 'SelectAll' and trigger total_select function with proper result , but when i do un-select/uncheck on 'SelectAll' none of my input get un-select/uncheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer as below, but still any one have any other best solution let me know , thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#SelectAll").click(function(){
           $(".checkBoxClass").trigger("click"); 
           $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', true);  
           $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked')); //add this line and working proper - hope will help someone
     }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can both solve your problem and improve code quality by using unobtrusive event handlers instead of outdated `on*` event attributes.

Firstly you can assign each `.checkBoxClass` its own `change` event handler, which can then read the meta data from some `data` attributes you place on the elements.

Then the select all logic can be simplified to check/uncheck all those elements, while triggering a `change` event to execute the handler. As you're using jQuery, here's an example:

```js
$('.checkBoxClass').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked)
    return;
    
  // place total_select() logic here, and read the parameters from the elements' data()
  console.log($(this).data());
});

$('#SelectAll').change(function() {
  $('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked', this.checked).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" />
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_1" value="1" data-a="1" data-b="0.35" data-c="2700.00" type="checkbox">A
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_2" value="2" data-a="2" data-b="0.35" data-c="2700.00" type="checkbox">B
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_3" value="3" data-a="3" data-b="0.35" data-c="2700.00" type="checkbox">C
```

Comment: on uncheck - selectall - the value should be none or blank for function

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: i cant place total_select() logic there as its used by some other checkbox id ... hence i cant repeat same function 2 place ...secondly i cant call data with three value ... data-a="1" data-b="0.35" data-c="2700.00", as here data-b and data-c are 2 different column value  and data-a is main primary id

Comment: The fact the function is used by another checkbox is not relevant - you can just call that function from this handler (or better yet, put that call in an unobtrusive handler too). Again your point about the data attributes make no sense. If you can place the value in the parameters of the `onclick` call, then you can put them in data attributes

Comment: hi, thanks , but cant it be done easily with $(".checkBoxClass").trigger("click"); .... it almost all perfect ... just on uncheck - selectall - all input are not getting uncheck

Comment: pls check i have update my question ,--  function ..., here i have just shown value 1,2,3 as a dummy ...but actually its coming dynamic from database php - mysql

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an active thread but I've jost sold a similar problem and I'd like to come out with the solution :D

With this, only those checkboxes will be checked or unchecked and (thus triggered )what have different `checked` property from `#SelectAll`.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#SelectAll').click(function () {
        $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') !== $('#SelectAll').prop('checked')) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
});

function total_select(id,carat,price){
  alert(id);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

ALL
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" />
A
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_1" value="1" onclick="javascript: total_select(1,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">
B
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_2" value="2" onclick="javascript: total_select(2,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">
C
<input class="checkBoxClass" name="pid[]" id="pid_3" value="3" onclick="javascript: total_select(3,0.35,2700.00);" type="checkbox">

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Add some description on your answer